# current_url loop stucks on random links

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to fetch current url for webpages that redirects to some other URLS when clicked upon.
However, the loop stucks on random pages. There is no consistency as to which page it will get stuck on. It doesn't even throw an error and goes into infinite loop.
few example of the final redirected link - it stucks on are -

https://www.bnnbloomberg.ca/amazon-predicted-its-slowest-ever-holiday-season-but-is-poised-to-surprise-1.1877911/

https://www.proactiveinvestors.co.uk/companies/news/1004924/shell-amazon-and-apple-head-busy-day-for-results-thursday-s-agenda-1004924.html/

I am not sure but it seems to be pop-up window/notification/alert/advertisement that loop can't pass through. I have tried including escape press, dismiss alert, switch to main window, but nothing seems to work for me,

Few Links from the list i am using is -

```
Link=['https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162418991?eventId=2f331d8e-1bbb-33a0-8174-30aa424a136d' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162420206?eventId=8be681bb-5739-3349-9aa4-3ae140d47548' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162418555?eventId=f486fa1c-5d6f-321b-9960-b14c7a15bd49' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162420946?eventId=58567a43-81a9-3a2e-a5ac-e50a90138ce5' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162421120?eventId=10aa9569-a69b-3f3a-90e4-013ff42aaf97' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162418992?eventId=9266999c-6003-37bb-93c3-afd52d775f09' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162422062?eventId=aa8b2344-e2db-3556-b2d9-dc85d1d83c9a' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162419497?eventId=cd6764d7-daf3-39a4-8d74-985d95b0bf24' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162422072?eventId=f2701b2f-0402-39ab-a72e-728b9b216299' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162418312?eventId=bae82bfa-b30d-3378-a53a-dd4326385af1' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162419135?eventId=677ed6fe-e4b8-3989-97df-fe6164fc71ed' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162419403?eventId=e7ae57c3-4f75-330d-a269-07528493edd5' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162418851?eventId=47a09a61-5beb-350b-a0f7-4e39bd3f8cf4' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162421562?eventId=efcbc9cf-ee2d-3582-9334-6ba67e335c8d' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162417353?eventId=c842db45-22b2-3b52-b3b6-7e4a67ac6b52' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162415817?eventId=8b345b91-7a70-3291-bc32-f1bde38f56a2' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162417836?eventId=5bc3eb70-304a-3c2d-bcb0-f4c737d1537e' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162416215?eventId=3ec86460-8913-3b4b-a0ee-ba5429f530ed' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162412269?eventId=d50ff2ba-3e59-3418-8eee-218264667b72' ,
'https://app.dnbhoovers.com/event/sourceArticleUrlRedirect/1/162416690?eventId=17720f16-1233-3c5e-9d4b-aaaade2792c0' ]
```

Code -

```
for i in Link:
    browser.get(i)
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'html')))
    try:
        all_iframes = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
        if len(all_iframes) > 0:
            browser.switch_to.parent_frame()
            browser.switch_to.default_content()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        alert=browser.switch_to.alert
        time.sleep(2)
        alert.dismiss()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        webdriver.ActionChains(browser).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        parent = browser.current_window_handle
        uselessWindows = browser.window_handles
        for winId in uselessWindows:
            if winId != parent: 
                browser.switch_to.window(winId)
                browser.close()
            browser.switch_to.window(parent)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        browser.find_element(By.xpath("//html")).click()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        redirectedlink.append(browser.current_url)
    except:
        redirectedlink.append(None)
    print(redirectedlink)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not handle the `WebDriveWait` for how much time it should wait on single page if expected element is not found.

There are chances some page shows custom pop-up/window/notification/alert/advertisement in such case your code will not work. (Basically you will have to visit each page and inspect the element and figure out xpath/id/css to write your conditions)

You can add such custom conditions by visiting individual page and if you want to escape such page then you can simply handle it using `from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException`

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, timout).until(...)
except TimeoutException as ex:
   pass
```

Comment: I did use that too, but it doesn't seem to work